# Self-Defined Python function didn't work

Tags: python

I just started learning Python. I following the textbook and created the a function as below:

```
 def Hello(name):
     print('Hello'+ name)

     Hello('Anne')
```

It should give me following answer:

```
Hello Anne
```

but nothing shown up, then I ran the code, it gives me:

```
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
======== RESTART: C:/Users/lampard1990/Desktop/Python/helloFunc 2.py ========
>>>
```

anyone knows why what happened? thanks

Comment: Indentation is very important in python. You have incorrectly indented the last line: `Hello('Anne')` should be at the same indentation level as `def Hello():` Currently you have just defined a (recursive) function, but have not called it. Note: `+` concatenates strings so you will get `'HelloAnne'` perhaps you meant `,`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the function without indentation. Here’s how it should look in order to avoid a trace back:

```
def Hello(name):
    print('Hello '+ name)

Hello('Anne')
```

When you call a function in Python, never have indentation. 
Also to get a space in the name, put a space after hello before the apostrophe. That will give you a space so that it types out Hello Anne

Answer (score 1):

You should do like this, indent matter in python.

```
def Hello(name):
  print('Hello '+ name)

Hello('Anne')
```

Comment: This prints `HelloAnne` not quite what the OP was looking for.

Comment: Works, amazing. this indent is really a matter for people fist use Python